# Similar triangles constructed by circumcircles of triangles in another triangle $ABC$

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have trouble solving this romanian olympiad question. I translated it:

> Let a point $D$ be chosen inside a triangle $A B C$. The centers
> of the circumcircles of the triangles $A B D, B C D$ and $CAD$ may be $C^{\prime}, A^{\prime}$ and $B^{\prime}$ respectively.
> Let the straight line $AD$ intersect the circumcircle of $BCD$ in $A^{\prime \prime}$. Let $B^{\prime \prime}$ and $C^{\prime \prime}$ be constructed accordingly.
> Prove that the triangles $A B C^{\prime \prime}, B C A^{\prime \prime}, C A B^{\prime \prime}$ and $A^{\prime} B^{\prime} C^{\prime}$ are similar.
> Is it possible, for any triangle $A B C$ to choose the point $D$ in such a way
> so that these four triangles are also similar to the triangle $A B C$?

Here is a visualization I constructed with geogebra

[image]

I started with the observation, that the triangles in the circumcircles coincide with one side of $ABC$. And if the triangle $ABC$ is equilateral and $D$ is exactly where the bisectors of its angles meet, the triangles have all the same size. My only trouble is proving it and creating a relation between $ABC$ and the triangle constructed by the midpoints of the circumcircles.

Comment: +1 : to your posting.  Being weak in Geometry, I am unsure how to solve your question.  However, I think that your posting is very clearly presented, with a complicated question, a good diagram, and reasonable work shown.

Comment: Try taking a general triangle and a general point D, as your current diagram seems to suggest that A, D, A', and A'' are collinear. And hint, chase angles using cyclic quadrilaterals.

Comment: Your prove is very understandable and comprehensible. +1 and thank you for your time. Is it correct that $D$ is exactly where the bisectors of its angles meet?

Comment: No, $D$ is not the intersection of angle bisectors. You are probably thinking so because if $D$ is the intersection of angle bisectors, then $ADA'A''$ is a straight line. But does that make $\triangle ABC$ similar? It is easy to show that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As $BDAC''$ is concyclic, $\angle C''AB = \angle C''DB$, which is equal to $\angle CDB''$ (since lines $CDC''$ and $BDB''$ are straight). And as $CDAB''$ is concyclic, $\angle CDB'' = \angle CAB''$. Also, as $BDCA''$ is concyclic, $\angle C''DB = \angle CA''B$. Proceed similarly with other angles and you will get that $\triangle A''BC \sim \triangle AB''C \sim \triangle ABC''$.

For $\triangle A'B'C'$, observe that $C'A'$ is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment $BD$ (since $C'A'$ is the line joining the centres of those two circles), and similarly $B'A'$ is the perpendicular bisector of $CD$. Therefore, in quadrilateral $A'EDF$, $\angle EDF + \angle EA'F = 180^\circ$. And also $\angle BDC + \angle BA''C = 180^\circ$. From these two equations we get $\angle C'A'B' = \angle BA''C$. Proceeding similarly with the other angles, we can prove the similarity of $\triangle A'B'C'$ as well.

Now think about the choice of point $D$ if I want $\triangle ABC$ similar too. Comment after that.

Comment: Can I show the similarity of $\triangle A'B'C'$ by angle chasing as well?

Comment: Yes, though that's slightly trickier. I will be adding that to my answer too, soon. Hint - Observe that $C'B'$ is the line joining the centres of those two circles, and so it is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment $AD$...

Comment: Okay after further examination I think it is where the heights of $ABC$ meet.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and that point is called the orthocentre. It would be a nice exercise to prove that orthocentre is the only point which makes $\triangle ABC$ similar too.

Comment: Do you have any hints on that?

Comment: Think about all the cases of $\triangle ABC$ being similar to $\triangle A''BC$. You should be able to reject all cases but one...